# Single word badge name for user post first story

Tags: single-word-requests

My app reward user when they write their first story(one line) on App.
Something similar to StackExchange reward student/teacher badge on posting first question/answer.

I'm searching some good name for the badge. The app users are writer/poet or anyone who like short writings.

Comment: How about ***Author***??

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cub.

Cub has been the adjective for new reporters on newspapers for years--as a noun or an adjective, e.g., cub reporter.  You could call them "cub writers" and increase the status to "junior writers" and so forth as they write more.

If you like you can establish levels, e.g., Cub1, Cub2, etc. You want a reward scheme that acknowledges and encourages without immediately elevating a new writer to the status of an experienced contributor.

From then on, it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a subjective question, there can be more than one correct answers.
As suggested in the comments too, [**Author**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/author) is pretty good-

> **Author**:
>
> A writer of a book, article, or document.

Apart from that, I would suggest [**Writer**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/writer) or [**Novelist**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/novelist).

> **Writer**
>
> A person who writes books, stories, or articles as a job or occupation.
>
> *‘Dickens was a prolific writer’*
>
> *‘a writer of short stories’*

For a slightly higher level, you could probably use [**Wordsmith**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wordsmith)-

> **Wordsmith**
>
> A skilled user of words.

By the way, the app looks neat!

Comment: Thanks @devon56 I think "Cub writer" would be better choice as Xanne's answer suggests. I liked "prolific writer" I will keep it for higher level badges. :)